# Redirect subdomain on tomcat through apache server with mod_jk

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-jk

I have a Tomcat (6.0.20) and Apache Server setup (2.2) and am trying to redirect all subdomains to a specific context, on my domain.

e.g., s.example.com redirect to www.example.com

Apache is fowarding requests via `mod_jk` (I tried `mod_proxy`, but the css and js didn't load as its not absolute urls).

My current setup:

httpd.conf:

```
Include C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/conf/auto/mod_jk.conf
RewriteEngine On
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.co.za
    ServerAlias www.example.co.za example.co.za *.example.co.za
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/rewrite.log" 
    RewriteLogLevel 3 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.co\.za.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.za [L] 
    JkMount /* worker1
</VirtualHost>
JkMount /* worker1
```

server.xml:

```
    <Host name="www.example.co.za" appBase="hosts/example"
         unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
          xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                directory="C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs" prefix="localhost_access_log."
                suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>

             <Context path="" docBase="Property"/>
              <Alias>*.example.co.za</Alias>
        </Host>
```

The redirect for ww.example.com is going into a non-stop redirect loop.

This is extremely important from a security point of view as the user could access the tomcat manager and other apps on the server (namely hudson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.za$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.co.za [L]
```

And if you want to keep the requested URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.za$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.co.za%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Additionally I recommend you to use a 301 redirection. So add the `R` flag with the value 301 by replacing `[L]` with `[L,R=301]`.